# Responding to an http request with JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, api, http

I have several Python scripts that are used from the CLI. Now I have been asked if I could provide a web API to perform some of the work normally done from the CLI. I would like to respond with JSON formatted data. I know little about JSON or API's.

How do I retrieve the query data from the http request?

How to a create the HTTP headers for the response from my script?

Given the following URL, how can I respond with a JSON reply of the name "Steve"?

```
http://myserver.com/api.py?query=who
```

I already have a functioning Apache web server running, and can serve up HTML and CGI scripts. It's simply coding the Python script that I need some help with. I would prefer not to use a framework, like Flask.

A simple code example would be appreciated.

The following is the Python code that I've come up with, but I know it's not the correct way to do this, and it doesn't use JSON:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7

import cgi        # CGI module

# Set page headers and start page 
print("Content-type: text/plain")
print("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a")

# Form defaults
query_arg = None

# Get form values, if any
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get the rest of the values if the form was submitted
if "query" in form.keys():
    query_arg = form["query"].value

if query_arg == "who":
    print("Steve", end="", flush=True)
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There are multiple frameworks for that: django rest framework, flask, aiohttp, fastAPI, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to build a request handler with core python code. which is able to handle http request, In my opinion its not good idea as there are multiple securty scenarios attached with it, also in cross server request its bit difficult to handle all request and request scenarios . I will suggest to use Flask which is very lightweight and this will give an pre-setup of routing mechanism to handle all kind of request in very less code below is the snippet to generate http json response hope it helps

```
import sys
import flask
import random, string
from flask import  jsonify

class Utils:
    def make_response(self):
        response = jsonify({
           'message': 'success',
        })
        response.status_code = 200
        return response
```